# Connection failed to localhost MySQL al crear una Base de Datos

Tags: mysql, genexus

En una instalación nueva de `Gx15 u10` al intentar conectar con una Base de Datos `MySQL 8.0.12` muestra el error de la captura:

> MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support
>   authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL
>   client.

Sin embargo, puedo crear o acceder a una DB con ese usuario directamente desde Workbench.

[image: Captura Error]

Comment: Bienvenido Bro, deberias poner el codigo que implementas en la conexcion, ya que asi sera mas facil de detectar el error...

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No hay mayor explicación porque es particular a Genexus y es la forma tradicional de hacer la conexión con un DataStore.

Comment: Estimado, que versión de MySQL estás usando? Gracias.

Comment: La versión es la 8.0.12. Pero, temporalmente, ya encontramos la solución.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8 soporta un nuevo tipo de autenticación, el cual requiere un nuevo driver de conexión:

[image: Nuevo Driver de Conexión]

Si se instala MySQL con éste nuevo método, es necesario utilizar el Driver mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar, ya que sino al momento de hacer un create de las tablas, se presenta el error:

> Error : Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Además de utilizar el nuevo driver, es necesario configurar la propiedad "MySQL version = 5.7.7 or higher", a nivel del DataStore.

En ejecución, si el driver no está actualizado el error es:

> HTTP Status 500 - com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)

Answer (score 0):

Para conectar con 'MySQL 8' (que por ahora solo funciona con Java)

1. Hay que reemplazar el driver que viene por defecto por **mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar** y copiarlo en la carpeta del modelo:

   > JavaModel\web\drivers
2. En el DataStore setear

   > **Use custom JDBC URL** = True
   >   **Custom JDBC URL** = &useSSL=false&skip-ssl